# Use a text box value as a variable in a Razor MVC 8 view

Tags: umbraco6, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I retrieve the text box value as a variable?

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="offset"/>

@{
   var offset = Request.Form["offset"]
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more context. Is your input in a form and you are posting and then retrieving the value?